# View Items are not visible in Main.StoryBoard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.4

Hi this is my first attempt to use xcode(6.4). I face one issue I created some viewContoller with Buttons,label etc. Once i shutdown my PC and start today now all the views are empty not showing anything in Main.StoryBoard. But once i run in emulator it is working. I am attaching here the screenshot.
[image: Document View]

And the ViewController in Main.StoryBoard like[image: ViewController]

I hope i do some blender mistake please anyone help me to find out.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thats that solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using size classes in your storyBoard, now if you add any of your controller for any specific view like this

[image]

After adding that view when you change your view like this

[image]

Then the previously added controller will be disabled for this view.

That added controller will be accessible for that view only.

Comment: Yes i fixed the issue. Can you help me with one thing if i want same design for iphone4s, iphone5, iphone6. Simply i want my design work in all devices. How can i do it?

Comment: Check some Adaptive Layout Tutorial for managing the views.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Comment: 1 more doubt i set it into for compactwidth|Any Height that is the issue. Now i want it to Any Height | Any Width . How can i do this? I hope Any Width Any Height will work in all devices so only i try this.

Comment: Yes,  Any Width Any Height is a generic view which will work for all devices.And add the controllers , so that it will work on all devices.

Comment: Now i want change from compact width | Any height to Any Width | Any Height. But it shows empty. Do i need to re design all the things?

Comment: Yes, you have to redesign the view.

Comment: Thanks. I have only idea with Android it is very much different from that. I will ask you if i have any questions

Answer (score 2):

You added those views for some particular size classes so for the maximum size classes those elements are not visible

Comment: Yes i fixed the issue. Can you help me with one thing if i want same design for iphone4s, iphone5, iphone6. Simply i want my design work in all devices. How can i do it?

Comment: I generally dont work with class sizes, rather i take the default class size and apply auto layout or rather i used to take the VC size for 3.5inc device and then apply autolayout so that every element gets placed accordingly